# installation of build-essential fails in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, aptitude

I'm trying to update my `gcc`, so [Linux Forums](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-help/104156-gcc-installation-ubuntu.html) recommended that I would run `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. Here's the output when I try to run `sudo apt-get install build-essential`:

> The following packages have unmet
>   dependencies:
>
> bunch of packages listed here
>
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install'
>   with no packages (or specify a
>   solution).

I wasn't sure if listing the actual missing packages would affect your advice. Please tell me how to proceed.

Note: I tried this command below but there were too missing dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get -f install build-essential
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is better suited for SuperUser.
Run: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: There are at least 10+ missing dependencies.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? The latest version is 10.04

Comment: I had 8.04... That might've been my issue :-/

Comment: yea, consider updating your OS. 8.04 and 10.04 should have separate repositories, so no conflicts should occur. 8.04 is Hardy right? What sources do you have in /etc/apt/sources.list?